# TypeError numpy.ndarray with scipy.optimize.minimize ('numpy.ndarray' object is not callable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, minimization

My environment is Python 3.74, running SciPy 1.3.1 and NumPy 1.17.2.
I'm trying to use the scipy.optimize.minimize function to find the minimum of a constrained nonlinear multivariable function, which I've built as `cost()`.
I'm running into a `TypeError` when I try and run the following code excerpt:

```
constraints = [
    {'type' : 'ineq', 'fun' : AA},
    {'type' : 'ineq', 'fun' : Ev},
    {'type' : 'eq', 'fun' : Aeq},
    {'type' : 'eq', 'fun' : Beq}
]
bnds = ((-5, 5))

z = minimize(lambda z: cost(z,to), x0=z0, constraints=constraints, method='SLSQP')
```

AA is (96,48), values from -0.5 to 0
Ev is (96,1), values of 3 and 5
Aeq is (5,1), all -0.5
Beq is 0

I assume the issue that none of these is'callable' as the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) states. If that's the case how do I make them so?

The traceback is as follows:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 313, in <listcomp>
    for c in cons['eq']]))
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 313, in _minimize_slsqp
    for c in cons['eq']]))
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 608, in minimize
    constraints, callback=callback, **options)
  File "F:\[redactedpath]\main.py", line 125, in <module>
    z = minimize(lambda z: cost(z,to), x0=z0, constraints=constraints, method='SLSQP')
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
```

I can't provide full code due to confidentiality but if you need more information please advise and I will reply.
Thankyou.

Comment: Please provide all the code of your file. The code you provided here is not enough for others to help you.

Comment: You/we/someone has to figure out where the error occurs, and what variable is an array instead of a function.

Comment: Examples for defining constraints are provided in the [tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#constrained-minimization-of-multivariate-scalar-functions-minimize).